# How can I avoid "clean+build" instead of just "build" in my VS2012 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, directx, buffer, directx-11

I'm programming a shader in DirectX (SharpDX). The thing is, I've noticed I need to clean and then build everytime I change something in the shader (.fx file). Is there any way to avoid having to do this? Before I made some changes, It looked like "Build" was enough to apply the changes... For instance. If I'm returning a red color for a line. I may change the color to green, the build and I'll still see it red. If I clean+build, I see the changes (lines in green).

I thought it may have to do with some buffer cleaning, but I'm not exactly sure.

Thanks a lot for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the shader compiler is coming along and compiling your shaders to .fxc bytecode. I believe Visual Studio doesn't keep track of changes to "external files" (i.e. not C#/C/C++/whatever code files), so when the program goes to run, it grabs the already compiled .fxc code, which has no new changes. Cleaning it removes those precompiled files, triggering a recompile. The easiest way to solve the problem is to add a custom build step in the Project Properties to run the DirectX shader compiler (fxc.exe) on your shader manually. You'll lose the nice property page stuff with it (assuming you were using them in the first place), but any time you compile your project, it'll recompile your shaders.

Comment: Ok I think that explains why I was having no problem with just "Build" (maybe when I was working on the .cs file mainly) and now I have to rebuild all the time (because I'm working mainly on my .fx file). Thanks!!